# How to change UTC to IST

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am trying to fetch Inv_date from database using this code and its working fine but I want to fetch the date according IST time zone because in database it follows UTC time zone. How can I do that?

```
 public DateTime? Inv_date { get; set; }
    public string TXNDate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Inv_date?.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should convert DateTime to the user's local timezone at the client-side (browser/app)

For now, you should try this:

```
 public DateTime? Inv_date { get; set; }
    public string TXNDate
    {
        get
        {
            return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(this.Inv_date, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time"));

        }
    }
```

PS: Not able to test this code.

Comment: It won't work because Ivn_date should be converted UTC by doing .ToUniversalTime()

Answer (score 0):

Here it is;

```
    public string TXNDate
    {
        get
        {
            if (Inv_date == null)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(Inv_date.GetValueOrDefault().ToUniversalTime(),
                TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        }
    }
```